# Kafka EOS retry flag

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-transactions, exactly-once

I have a Kafka cluster and a spring boot application that is configured for EOS. The application consumes from topic A performs some business logic then produces to topic B.
The issue i am facing if EOS fails to write to topic B it retries and all my business logic is executed again. This is a problem for me as I then duplicate the API call. Is there a flag of some sort when a retry occurs so i can then skip the business logic and go straight to produce?

KafkaConsumerConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.server}")
    String server;

    @Value("${kafka.consumer.groupid}")
    String groupid;

    @Autowired
    Tracer tracer;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, TransactionAvroEntity> consumerFactory() {

        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, server);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupid);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, AvroDeserializer.class);

        config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, "read_committed");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 120000);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 10000);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 15000);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 120000);

        return new TracingConsumerFactory<>(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(),
                new AvroDeserializer<>(TransactionAvroEntity.class)), tracer);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, TransactionAvroEntity> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            KafkaAwareTransactionManager<Object, Object> transactionManager) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, TransactionAvroEntity> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, TransactionAvroEntity>();

        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setAutoStartup(false);
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.BATCH);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setEosMode(EOSMode.ALPHA);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factory.setConcurrency(5);

        return factory;
    }

}
```

KafkaProducerConfig

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.server}")
    String server;
        
    @Autowired
    public Tracer tracer;
    
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, TransactionAvroEntity> producerFactory() {
        
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, server);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, AvroSerializer.class.getName());       
        config.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, "tranDec-1");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG,"snappy");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, "200");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, Integer.toString(256*1024));
        config.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_CONFIG,120000);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,60000);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, 5);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, Integer.toString(32768* 1024));
        config.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, "com.EXAMPLE.config.KafkaCustomPatitioner");
        
        return new TracingProducerFactory<>(new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config), tracer);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, TransactionAvroEntity> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public KafkaAwareTransactionManager<?, ?> kafkaTransactionManager(ProducerFactory<String, TransactionAvroEntity> producerFactory) {
        return new KafkaTransactionManager<>(producerFactory);
    }
     

}
```

KafkaTopicProducer

```
@Service
public class KafkaTopicProducer {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, TransactionAvroEntity> kafkaTemplate;

    public void topicProducer(TransactionAvroEntity payload, String topic, Headers headers) {

        ProducerRecord<String, TransactionAvroEntity> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<String, TransactionAvroEntity>(topic, null, payload.getNumber(), payload,
                headers);
        kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord);

    }
}
```

KafkaConsumer

```
@Service
public class KafkaConsumerTransaction {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumerTransaction.class);

    @Autowired
    TransactionEnrichmentService enrichmentService;

    @Autowired
    KafkaTopicProducer kafkaTopicProducer;

    @Value("${kafka.producer.topic.transactionDecouplingException}")
    String exceptionTopic;

    @Autowired
    JaegerTrace tracer;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;



    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.consumer.topic.transaction}", groupId = "${kafka.consumer.groupid}", id = "${kafka.consumer.listenerid}")
    public boolean consume(List<ConsumerRecord<String, TransactionAvroEntity>> records, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
        // loop through batch read
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, TransactionAvroEntity> record : records) {

            Integer partition = record.partition();
            Long offset = record.offset();
            TransactionAvroEntity te = record.value();

            try {

                

if (enrichmentService.enrichAndValidateTransactions(te, partition, offset, record)) {
    
//Do some logic
                    } else {
//Do some logic
                    }
    
                } catch (Exception e) {
    //Do some logic

                }
kafkaTopicProducer.topicProducer(t, topic, record.headers());
            }
            return true;
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: You might need to separate logic where once kafka consumer consumes message from one topic put those messages into one data structure (may be `list`)  & then hand off that list to kafka producer so that it will sequentially produce message to another kafka topic. 
Reason is I am seeing `MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG` in consumer is same as `TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_CONFIG` so there is possibility that kafka consumer is re-reading message & sending it to kafka producer as per above code.

Comment: Why do you need separate consumer and producer? Have you looked at Spring Cloud Stream **Kafka Streams** binder?

Comment: The same semantics apply when using the binder (`consume->process`) is at least once, only the entire `consume->process->publish` is exactly once).

Answer (score 0):

EOS applies to the entire `consume->process->publish` only.

The `consume->process` part is at least once.

You need to make the process part idempotent.

A common technique is to store the topic/partition/offset along with other data in the `process` so you can check whether this record has already been processed.

You can enable the delivery attempt header, but that will only tell you that this is a redelivery, it can't tell you whether the failure was at the start of the `process` or at the end (during the send).