# How to configure DLQ in a stateful application with Spring-Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka, stateful, dead-letter

I need to create an application using stateful retry, that listen to a Kafka topic and make calls to some APIs and then commit the message. If in one of these calls an error occurs, for example a timeout, the application must retry 4 attempts with an interval of 4 seconds. At the end of these four attempts, if it still hasn't worked, the application should send it to a DLQ topic.

The part of sending to the DLQ topic that I'm not able to do. Because when I tried to configure the DLQ, the retry don't stop and not send to DLQ too.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${topic.name}", concurrency = "1")
public void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, AberturaContaLimiteCreditoCalculado> mensagem,
                    @Headers final MessageHeaders headers,
                    Acknowledgment ack) {
    AberturaContaLimiteCreditoCalculadoData dados;
    if (!validarMensagem(mensagem)) {
        dados = mensagem.value().getData();
        throw new RuntimeException();
        //ack.acknowledge();
        //This throw Runtime it's just to force it to retry.
    }
}

private boolean validarMensagem(ConsumerRecord<String, AberturaContaLimiteCreditoCalculado> mensagem) {
    return mensagem == null || mensagem.value() == null;
}
```

KafkaConfig:

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(final ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory) {
    final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory
            = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
    factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler(
            publisherRetryDLQ(),
            new FixedBackOff(4000L, 4L)));
    return factory;
}

public DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer publisherRetryDLQ() {
    return new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(createKafkaTemplate(),
            (record, ex) -> new TopicPartition(topicoDLQ, 0));
}

public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    final Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, keySerializer);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, valueSerializer);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
}

public KafkaOperations<String, String> createKafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
```

**Edit 2022-05-04:**

We managed, from your tip with RetryListener and logging.level with Debug, to find the problem that was not building the Producer.

The problem now is that we receive a consumer with a different avro from the DLQ avro. The difference is that the DLQ has an extra field that must store the reason for the error.

```
2022/05/04 16:53:43.675 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] [ERROR] o.s.k.l.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer - Dead-letter publication to limites-abertura-conta-limite-credito-calculado-convivenciaaberturaconta-dlq failed for: limites-abertura-conta-limite-credito-calculado-0@6
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema{...}]}}]}
```

Is there a way to do this conversion?

Comment: Configuration looks fine on the face of it; try DEBUG logging, add a `RetryListener` to the error handler to monitor retries; if you still can't figure it out, post a minimal, complete, reproducible example someplace so someone can take a look to see what's wrong with the config.

Comment: With your tip we managed to get the producer to be created, which was the problem. Now we found a new challenge, I edited the question with the error we are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, you want to create a `ProducerRecord` with a different value type.

Simply subclass the DLPR and override `createProducerRecord()`.

```java
    /**
     * Subclasses can override this method to customize the producer record to send to the
     * DLQ. The default implementation simply copies the key and value from the consumer
     * record and adds the headers. The timestamp is not set (the original timestamp is in
     * one of the headers). IMPORTANT: if the partition in the {@link TopicPartition} is
     * less than 0, it must be set to null in the {@link ProducerRecord}.
     * @param record the failed record
     * @param topicPartition the {@link TopicPartition} returned by the destination
     * resolver.
     * @param headers the headers - original record headers plus DLT headers.
     * @param key the key to use instead of the consumer record key.
     * @param value the value to use instead of the consumer record value.
     * @return the producer record to send.
     * @see KafkaHeaders
     */
    protected ProducerRecord<Object, Object> createProducerRecord(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record,
            TopicPartition topicPartition, Headers headers, @Nullable byte[] key, @Nullable byte[] value) {
```

You can examine the headers to determine the exception that caused the failure. If you need the actual exception, override `accept()` to capture it in a `ThreadLocal`, then call `super.accept()`; you can then use the thread local in `createProducerRecord()`.

There are several solutions to publish the different type with the same producer factory.

- you can us a `DelegatingByTypeSerializer` see [KafkaConsumer With Multiple Different Avro Producers And Transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72060398/kafkaconsumer-with-multiple-different-avro-producers-and-transactions/72099146#72099146) for an example
- you can configure the publisher with a `KafkaTemplate` that uses a different  serializer (it has a constructor where you can override the producer factory configs).

Comment: I used the solution of extending the DLPR class and overriding createProducerRecord. And it worked perfectly, thank you very much for your help and your time. You are amazing.